Applying vector decomposition multiple times and RH orthonormal bases
I want to show that I can write any 3D vector $v$ in components with respect to the right handed orthonormal basis $\{e_1, e_2, e_3\}$ (i.e. three perpendicular unit vectors $\{e_1, e_2, e_3\}$ such that $e_1 \times e_2 = e_3$, $e_2 \times e_3 = e_1$, and $e_3 \times e_1 = e_2$) as $v = v_1 e_1 + v_2 e_2 + v_3 e_3$ with $v_i = v \cdot e_i \in \mathbb{R}$.
I want to do this via the fact that any 3D vector can be uniquely decomposed with respect to a chosen unit vector as $v = v_e + v_{e^\perp}$, where $v_e = (v \cdot e)e$ and $v_{e^\perp} = v - v_e$.
Have applied decomposition once.    Eqn.1:
\begin{equation}
v = (v \cdot e_1)e_1 + v_{e_1}^\perp    
\end{equation}
Have applied decomposition again.    Eqn.2:
\begin{equation}
v_{e_1}^\perp = \left( v_{e^1}^\perp \cdot e_2 \right) e_2 + {v_e^p}
\end{equation}
Subbing (Eqn.2) into (Eqn.1).
\begin{equation}
v = (v \cdot e_1) e_1 + \left( v_{e^1}^\perp \cdot e_2 \right) e_2 + {v_e^p}
\end{equation}
Rearranging and subbing (Eqn.1) into (Eqn.2).
\begin{equation}
v_{e^1}^\perp = \left[ (v  - \left[ (v \cdot e_1) e_1 \right] ) \cdot e_2 \right] e_2 + v_e^p
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
v_{e^1}^\perp = \left[ (v \cdot e_2) e_2 \right] + v_e^p
\end{equation}
As $e_1 \cdot e_2 = 0$ since $e_2 \times e_3 = e_1$.
Now,
\begin{equation}
v = (v \cdot e_1) e_1 + (v \cdot e_2) e_2 + v_{e}^p
\end{equation}
Not sure where to show I obtain the component representation after this step but I have tried to use decomposition again to show $ v_{e}^p=(v \cdot e_{3})e_3 $:
\begin{equation}
v_e^p = \left( {v_e^p} \cdot e_3 \right) e_3 + c \cdot e_1 + d \cdot e_2?
\end{equation}
How do I go about showing that this component representation is unique w.r.t the RH basis we started with?
